# switching between tabs got library errors

Tags: reactjs, react-router

hello I am working on react app in which i got two may be library error.
while switching between tags.

```
ReactReconciler.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

and

```
ReactCompositeComponent.js:242 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentWillUnmount' of null
```

I spent hours on it.thanks for your any help

This is the code to switching between tabs.which working previously good but when I clone it to deferent machine its throws error like above.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');

var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;

var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var ButtonToolbar = ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar;
var Nav = ReactBootstrap.Nav;
var Navbar = ReactBootstrap.Navbar;
var NavItem = ReactBootstrap.NavItem;
var Tabs = ReactBootstrap.Tabs;
var Tab = ReactBootstrap.Tab;


var Subtab = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function () {
    var path = window.location.href;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

if(path.indexOf('transaction') > 0) {
  $('#transaction').addClass('active');
  $('#portfolio').removeClass('active');
  $('#tax').removeClass('active');

}else if(path.indexOf('tax') > 0) {
  $('#tax').addClass('active');
  $('#transaction').removeClass('active');
  $('#portfolio').removeClass('active');

}else{
  $('#transaction').removeClass('active');
  $('#portfolio').addClass('active');
  $('#tax').removeClass('active');
}
},

  render: function() {
    return (
     <div>
     <br/>
        <Nav bsStyle="tabs" style={{ 'position': 'relative','top': '2px'}}>
          <NavItem id="portfolio" href={'#/portfolio/' + this.props.portfolioId}><b>Portfolio Details</b></NavItem>
          <NavItem id="transaction"  href={'#/portfolio/' +  this.props.portfolioId + '/transaction'}><b>Transaction</b></NavItem>
          <NavItem id="tax" href={'#/portfolio/' + this.props.portfolioId      + '/tax'}><b>Taxation</b></NavItem>
        </Nav>
     </div>
    );
  }
});
```

module.exports = Subtab;

Comment: You have to provide a lot more code related to your app and problem. And I mean **alot** more. It's impossible to help you right now with the limited info given.